# Trying to save data to CSV. No error but nothing is saved

Tags: r

This scrapes data fine.

```
library(XML)
require(reshape2)

# URL of interest:
mps <- "http://stockreports.nasdaq.edgar-online.com/aapl.html"
# parse the document for R representation:
mps.doc <- htmlParse(mps)
# get all the tables in mps.doc as data frames
mps.tabs <- readHTMLTable(mps.doc)

mat <- melt(mps.tabs)
```

`mps.tabs` looks fine. I can't save it to a CSV file though. I keep getting and error.

```
mat <- melt(mps.tabs)
write.csv(mat, file = "C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/MyData.csv")
```

Nothing gets saved to my CSV. No error message; just nothing. Can someone let me know what is wrong here?

Comment: Your program doesn't work on my  computer  ; mat <- melt(mps.tabs) returns an error. What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Maybe try setting your path prior to saving the csv file, then just save the file MyData in the current working path

Comment: Instead of reading in the entire page into mps.tab, maybe you should try to read table by table approach.  Also, you may want look at the rvest and XML2 packages, I find these libraries an improvement over xml.

Comment: It looks like you're on Windows. Don't the separators in the path have to be \ rather than /?

Comment: If you're trying to grab _all_ the tables (some of which are pretty worthless), with `rvest` you can just do `mps %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)`. You'll probably want to do some cleaning, though. Chuck `melt()` on the end of that chain, if you want.

Comment: Sorry, everyone, this is probably close, but I'm getting an error.

mps %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
Error: could not find function "%>%"

Yes, Windows.  The path to my desktop is fine as is.  If you run my 5 lines of code, without comments, and then enter this: 'mps.tabs'...
I want to see that saved in a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it!

```
library(XML)
stocks = "http://stockreports.nasdaq.edgar-online.com/aapl.html"
stocks.table = readHTMLTable(airline, header=T, which=1,stringsAsFactors=F)
write.csv(stocks.table, file = "C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/MyData.csv")
```